# How do gadgets work in Vector?

Tags: ouya, vector

There are two gadgets available in the store: Slow Time and Force Blaster. I bought Slow Time and equipped it, but I don't see it available while playing. How do I use a gadget after I bought it? Are they single use? Are there more gadgets to unlock?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that this question is specific to the ouya version of the game? If not, the ouya tag is unnecessary.

Comment: I think there might be an Ouya specific bug causing the gadgets not to actually equip when I try to equip them, which is why I included the tag.

Comment: I see. Carry on, then.

Answer (score -1):

When you click on this gadget during the game, it will work.
Slow time, make the game slow .
Force Blaster, make you safe against one touch by the enemy.

Comment: What do you mean by "click on it"? Last time I tried, there was no visible indication that the gadgets I had equipped were available.